# Bootstrap date picker end date is not working

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

```
$("SELECTOR").datepicker({
 autoclose: true,
 todayHighlight: true,
 format: {
      toDisplay: function (date, format, language) {
           return moment(date).utc().format(format1);
      },
      toValue: function (date, format, language) {
           var date1 = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
           var d = new Date(date1);
           d.setDate(d.getDate() + 0);
           return new Date(d);
      }
 },
 language:"en",
 endDate: '+0d'});
```

Here due to format code the end date is not working, and I can not remove that too, I want to disable all the future dates with this code, please suggest any solution.

[image]

Comment: Can you setup a JSFiddle with your problem?

Comment: @iamdlm here is the Findel link [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jenish_lila/8kazue9o/1/) , i have tried to select date and same case as mine, but i am unable, try if you can

Comment: In which format do you want the date?

Comment: Check [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zndtjoy/) and see if helps.

Comment: @iamdlm I want in 2 formats first will be dynamic(e.g: 'dd/mm/yyyy') and another one in 'MM/DD/YYYY', I want to allow 2 formats